# Uninstall a module that is not a composer package?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uninstall

Is there a way to discard/revert the changes I made with `InstallData/UpgradeData` scripts without having to go to database and revert changes there manually?

I know there is `Uninstall.php`, but it only works if your module is a composer package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO there is not (at least at the time I'm writing this).
The uninstall file, as you say, is only executed for composer installed packages.
For other modules you have to remove manually what you added via the install/update scripts.

Comment: @Rudolph I hear ya. It would be nice to make it work for all modules.

Comment: I agree with the statement that this sucks. Can anyone share some insight on why they added this constraint?